# Simple clock using dojo in javascript

Tags: javascript, time, dojo

I need to a simple clock application without any user interface, just like this >

```
Time: 15.06.2012 18:34:21
```

It should change in real time. I mean that in second it should be `15.06.2012 18:34:22`
Should I use `timer`? Or what?

I am using dojo 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setInterval function:

HTML:

```
<span id="time">TIME:</span>
```

Javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("time");
setInterval(function(){
    var time = (new Date()).toLocaleString();
    elem.innerHTML = "TIME: " +time;              
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Andrei said:
http://jsfiddle.net/8DnVU/